# Stastical Distance QQ-Plot

Tags: r, statistics

I am following along some lecture materials and at a point where I want to plot the residuals of a mlm model in R.

Looking at the iris dataset in R

```
data('iris')
iris.lm<-lm(cbind(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) ~ Species, data = iris) 
iris.fit<-manova(iris.lm)
iris.summary<-summary(iris.fit,test="Wilks")

iris.res<-residuals(iris.fit)
iris.res
```

I get the correct residuals:

```
| Sepal.Length | Sepal.Width |
|       ------ |      ------ |
|         0.094|        0.072|
|        -0.106|       10.428|
```

but how do I make the jump to plotting these residuals onto a chi-sq qqplot?
[image]

Comment: Sorry for the table, its formatted properly when I edit the question but doesnt display the same way.

Comment: Not sure how you did the plot, maybe `qqnorm(qchisq(iris.fit$residuals, 2))`?